# Centos 7.6 RAID5 physical system will not boot after single drive failure

Tags: linux, centos7, boot, software-raid

Hello,

I recently built a Centos 7.6 server with 4 identical 500GB drives, using the Anaconda installer from a local Centos 7.6 DVD. The BIOS settings give me EFI rather than bios boot.

Using "manual partitioning" in the disk sub-menu, I generated a small four-way RAID1 mirror holding the "/boot" and "/boot/efi" mount points. As best as I can tell this mirror uses software RAID via 'md', and does not use 'lvm'. I created "/", "/var", "/home", and "swap" as LVM mount points within a maximally-sized RAID5 array. On completing the install I see the following drive layout:

```
$ lsblk
NAME                       MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                          8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk  
├─sda1                       8:1    0     1G  0 part  
│ └─md127                    9:127  0  1023M  0 raid1 /boot
├─sda2                       8:2    0     1G  0 part  
│ └─md125                    9:125  0     1G  0 raid1 /boot/efi
└─sda3                       8:3    0 463.8G  0 part  
  └─md126                    9:126  0   1.4T  0 raid5 
    ├─centos_reports2-root 253:0    0   100G  0 lvm   /
    ├─centos_reports2-swap 253:1    0  19.9G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    ├─centos_reports2-var  253:2    0 299.9G  0 lvm   /var
    └─centos_reports2-home 253:3    0  49.9G  0 lvm   /home
sdb                          8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk  
├─sdb1                       8:17   0     1G  0 part  
│ └─md127                    9:127  0  1023M  0 raid1 /boot
├─sdb2                       8:18   0     1G  0 part  
│ └─md125                    9:125  0     1G  0 raid1 /boot/efi
└─sdb3                       8:19   0 463.8G  0 part  
  └─md126                    9:126  0   1.4T  0 raid5 
    ├─centos_reports2-root 253:0    0   100G  0 lvm   /
    ├─centos_reports2-swap 253:1    0  19.9G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    ├─centos_reports2-var  253:2    0 299.9G  0 lvm   /var
    └─centos_reports2-home 253:3    0  49.9G  0 lvm   /home
sdc                          8:32   0 465.8G  0 disk  
├─sdc1                       8:33   0     1G  0 part  
│ └─md127                    9:127  0  1023M  0 raid1 /boot
├─sdc2                       8:34   0     1G  0 part  
│ └─md125                    9:125  0     1G  0 raid1 /boot/efi
└─sdc3                       8:35   0 463.8G  0 part  
  └─md126                    9:126  0   1.4T  0 raid5 
    ├─centos_reports2-root 253:0    0   100G  0 lvm   /
    ├─centos_reports2-swap 253:1    0  19.9G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    ├─centos_reports2-var  253:2    0 299.9G  0 lvm   /var
    └─centos_reports2-home 253:3    0  49.9G  0 lvm   /home
sdd                          8:48   0 465.8G  0 disk  
├─sdd1                       8:49   0     1G  0 part  
│ └─md127                    9:127  0  1023M  0 raid1 /boot
├─sdd2                       8:50   0     1G  0 part  
│ └─md125                    9:125  0     1G  0 raid1 /boot/efi
└─sdd3                       8:51   0 463.8G  0 part  
  └─md126                    9:126  0   1.4T  0 raid5 
    ├─centos_reports2-root 253:0    0   100G  0 lvm   /
    ├─centos_reports2-swap 253:1    0  19.9G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    ├─centos_reports2-var  253:2    0 299.9G  0 lvm   /var
    └─centos_reports2-home 253:3    0  49.9G  0 lvm   /home
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md125 : active raid1 sdb2[0] sdd2[2] sdc2[1] sda2[3]
      1049536 blocks super 1.0 [4/4] [UUUU]
      bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md126 : active raid5 sdb3[1] sdc3[2] sdd3[4] sda3[0]
      1458462720 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
      bitmap: 2/4 pages [8KB], 65536KB chunk

md127 : active raid1 sdd1[2] sdb1[0] sdc1[1] sda1[3]
      1047552 blocks super 1.2 [4/4] [UUUU]
      bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices:
$
```

All four drives are partitioned identically, as follows:

```
# fdisk /dev/sdd

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sdd: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000f06c8

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1   *        2048     2101247     1049600   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdd2         2101248     4200447     1049600   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdd3         4200448   976773119   486286336   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Command (m for help): q
```

I want to be able to survive a single drive failure, and as best as understand RAID1 and RAID5 I should be able to do so. Yet, when I shut down the server and and simulate a drive failure by pulling a drive, the server will not come up.

I do see the grub menu, and I do see the attempt to boot into Centos 7. I watch the various different-colored lines crawl all the way across the botton of the console. But then the process falls to the emergency boot prompt, with errors saying that /dev/centos_reports2-root and /dev/centos_reports2-swap do not exist and suggests that I save "/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt" to a USB stick and submit a bug report. Exiting the shell results in an identical failure. If  I halt the system, power down, re-insert the drive, and power back up, then it boots normally.

I hope that there is a way to get this to work as it ought to. Centos 7 should be able to construct the RAID5 and run with it in a degraded state, and it would be on me to replace the failed drive.

Now, perhaps if I had pulled the sda drive, I may not have even gotten this far. I have not manually written the boot loader to every drive; maybe if I  pulled sda I wouldn't even get to the Centos boot attempt. It seems to me that the Anaconda installer should put the boot loader on every drive that is part of a metadevice containing "/" and/or "/boot/efi", but I do not know if it does so. (I'm pretty sure earlier versions did not.) In any case, that is a separate issue.

Should I be using RAID-somethingelse where I used RAID5? I've encountered several sources that recommend RAID10 instead of RAID5. Would my system boot if I had done so? Or is there some other thing I am doing wrong?

When I run "journalctl" in the emergency shell, The line that fails is very near the end. As best as I can tell everything was normal up to:

```
. . . . . . . .
sd :1:0:0:0 [sda] Attached SCSI disk
random: fast init done
mgag200 0000 04:03:0: fb0: mgadrmfb frame buffer device
[drm] initialized mgag200 1:0:0 20110418 for 0000:04:03:0: on minor 0
Job dev-mapper-centos_myhost\x2droot.device/start timed out
[TIME] timed out waiting for device dev-mapper-centos_myhost\x2droot.device
Dependency failed ...
Dependency failed ...
. . . . . . . .
```

This happens even after I made some changes and tried re-installing. I changed my BIOS Firmware boot options from "UEFI and Legacy" to "UEFI Only", and reinstalled Centos with just two drives configured in a mirror. The /boot and /boot/efi partitions are the same as before (save on a 2-way rather than 4-way mirror), and the other partitions again are lvm on a maximally-sized RAID array, this time RAID1 of the two drives rather than RAID5 with four drives.
There were noticeable effects of these changes. Anaconda wrote GPT rather than DOS labels on the two drives, and the install included the "efibootmgr" package by default. "efibootmgr -v" now works, instead of failing with a message about EFI variables not being supported.

But the system still cannot boot when I take away one of the drives and again, the 'md' driver should be able to run the mirror configuration in a degraded state. Are there perhaps configuration options I need to supply to the md software? I will try and submit this as a bug report, though again any advice is welcome.

Comment: I don't think you can RAID the EFI system partition; the BIOS won't understand Linux software RAID. Your disks also haven't been GPT partitioned, which will cause you trouble later.

Comment: The Anaconda for 7.1 or thenabouts would not even let me create /boot/efi as part of a RAID device. On 7.6 ( and 7.5, maybe 7.4) I can, and as long as I don't take away any disks the system happily boots. It even finds Centos in my situation, so I assume it must be reading /boot/efi.

I'd also like to see GPT instead of DOS partitions but I didn't do that; Anaconda did, and I did not notice anyplace to make that choice. How can you make Anaconda do differently?

In any case, my concern is with the RAID5, not the RAID1 where /boot/efi sits.

Comment: @MichaelHampton , I edited the question to say that reinstalling after changing the BIOS boot options to "UEFI Only" instead of "Legacy and UEFI" gave me GPT disklabels, but did not solve the larger problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is less of an actual solution to my problem, and more of a realization that my expectations of "md+lvm" software RAID were perhaps more than realistic. I was perhaps asking too much to expect "md+lvm" to boot with a hard disk suddenly and mysteriously vanished.  When a drive (or a partition of a drive) in a RAID configuration actually becomes faulty during use, it will over time generate various errors in log files, etc, and the 'md' RAID software will experience failures in trying to use that drive and/or partition.

Eventually the 'md' software will 'fail' that component, or mark it as faulty. You can see this via "cat /proc/mdstat", in this case showing that the /dev/sdb1 component of the md125 RAID1 mirror is faulty:

```
[root@host ~]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] 
md125 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1](F)
      1049536 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [U_]
      bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
.  .  .  .  .
[root@host ~]#
```

Using the "mdadm" administrative utility, you can simulate such a failure via:

```
mdadm --manage /dev/md125 --fail /dev/sdb1
```

(That's how I produced the above output.) The command:

```
mdadm --manage /dev/md125 --remove /dev/sdb1
```

then removes the failed component from the metadevice configuration, and the metadevice runs on the remaining components. When a partition or drive really does fail, then before you can pull the drive it is necessary to 'fail' and 'remove' every partition of that drive from the metadevices of which they are components. After I simulated a drive failure and response by doing all this, I was able to successfully shut down, pull the drive, reboot the unit and it came back up into Centos successfully. All the metadevices (RAID1 mirrors) ran on single sub-mirrors:

```
[root@reports2 ~]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] 
md125 : active raid1 sda1[0]
      1049536 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [U_]
      bitmap: 1/1 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk

md126 : active raid1 sda2[0]
      1047552 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
      bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md127 : active raid1 sda3[0]
      974529536 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
      bitmap: 3/8 pages [12KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: 
[root@reports2 ~]#
```

I did not really have a bad drive, so I just shut down, put the drive back in, rebooted, and added the /dev/sdb components back into their respective metadevices via commands like:

```
mdadm --manage /dev/md125 --add /dev/sdb1
```

After doing this with all the mirrors, they will re-sync. The larger the mirror the longer it takes:

```
[root@reports2 ~]# !cat
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] 
md125 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      1049536 blocks super 1.0 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md126 : active raid1 sdb2[2] sda2[0]
      1047552 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md127 : active raid1 sdb3[2] sda3[0]
      974529536 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
      [>....................]  recovery =  0.0% (883968/974529536) finish=91.7min speed=176793K/sec
      bitmap: 3/8 pages [12KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: 
[root@reports2 ~]#
```

With a real drive failure, it is of course necessary to first partition the replacement drive identically as the remaining one. Though I did not really need to, I followed the instructions at:

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/linux-raid-replace-failed-harddisk/

And used the "gdisk" utility to conveniently duplicate the /dev/sda GPT partition table onto /dev/sdb via:

```
sgdisk -R /dev/sdb /dev/sda
sgdisk -G /dev/sdb
```

The above link recommends "gdisk" as reliable for GPT disklabels/partition-tables. The first command does the actual copy (from "/dev/sda" to "/dev/sdb", perhaps a little counter-intuitively) and the second generates unique UUIDs for /dev/sdb and it's partitions.